# Using Orca To Change Service

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer, orca

I have a Windows Service I created that I want to install multiple times on the same server without having to create multiple duplicate VS projects.  Is there a way to use Orca to edit the MSI file to this end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, but it's not easy. Basically, you need to generate multiple transforms which represent different instances of your product:

- use Transform -> New Transform menu to start creating a transform
- change the ProductCode and ProductName properties in Property table
- change your service name
- save the transform
- do the same for the other instances you want to have
- when installing the package, use one of the transforms:
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490766.aspx